# Why can't I log in a website that I have saved cookie data from?

Tags: browser, cookies

I came across this Extension called [EditThisCookie](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/editthiscookie/fngmhnnpilhplaeedifhccceomclgfbg?hl=en) that can import and export cookies. So I did an experiment…

I first exported the cookies from Facebook while logged in, and then I logged out. Then I imported the cookies. And I did not see myself log in. I obviously dont understand how this works. Help?

- Does logging out cancel my current cookies?
- If I dont log out and take the cookies to another computer will that work?

Comment: Unless you get a facebook programmer to answer this question we can only work off assumptions. Generally logging out from a website invalidates the cookie. Also, copying a cookie to another browser, even on the same computer, shouldn't work if the website has implemented good login security.

Comment: The cookie is tied to a session. The session is destroyed when you logout, and the cookie is no good.

Comment: Cookies being tied to a session on the server is *generally* the reason why if you logged out you cannot just login again with simply the cookie. But in the case of many websites like Facebook nowadays — where identity theft prevention and security measures are tight — their validation process also checks for lots of other things. Such as your browser’s user agent and even geolocation tied with canvas fingerprinting. So simply grabbing a cookie — even if you did not log out — an placing it on another machine won’t just log you in any best; flag you as being hacked at worst.

Comment: Thank you all for the good info.. I wanted to upvote u all but I get this error:  "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."    Sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does logging out cancel my current cookies?

This technically depends on the website, but the general answer is likely yes.

> If I don't log out and take the cookies to another computer, will that work?

Again, this technically depends on the website, but ideally websites with good security won't allow this.

> I obviously don't understand how this works... Help?

When someone requests resources from a web server via HTTP, typically the web server gives them whatever they request and that's that.

If a web server wants to keep track of a client (e.g. if someone is "logged in"), one of the mechanisms used is to send that client a cookie. The cookie is then sent back to the server with each client request. The server reads the cookie each time the client sends it and acts accordingly.

However, as soon as the web server decides the cookie is no longer valid (because e.g. it registers that someone has "logged out", requests are coming from a different IP, a certain amount of time has elapsed, etc.), the cookie becomes worthless and there is little use in retaining it client-side.

Comment: Well, as [I pointed out in my comment](https://superuser.com/questions/1526768/why-cant-i-log-in-a-website-that-i-have-saved-cookie-data-from#comment2314629_1526768), sessions are only one part of the identity chain on modern websites. Other factors have to match to valid device identity. Facebook definitely uses heuristic profiles to confirm identities online.

Comment: Thank you all for the good info, im now satisfied that i understand .. I wanted to upvote u all but I get this error:  "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."    Sorry

Comment: @Hosa Not a problem. Thanks for the consideration, regardless. Glad to hear that you have a little clearer idea of what's happening. =)